# is there any option to give management or service port as system arguement in wso2 other than portOffset?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I wanted to pass the management console port(specified in catalina-server) and service http port(specified in axis2.xml) as system properties (using -DmgmntPort=9292 -DservPort=8282) while starting wso2 server. I tried -DhttpsPort but not working. please help

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an option to allow such usage. I looked into startup script and found, that port always by default 9443, but you can configure offset.

It means if u have offset 10 then actual port number will be 9453 = 9443 + 10

example of such command bellow. Lets consider that u distribution located in **/var/lib/wso2esb-4.9.0**
rename WSO_HOME/repository/conf/carbon.xml  to carbon.original.xml

then add to startup script handler for input variale of offset. Lets call it **offset**

command

```
 sed "s/<Offset>0<\/Offset>/<Offset>$offset<\/Offset>/" /var/lib/wso2esb-4.9.0/repository/conf/carbon.original.xml > /var/lib/wso2esb-4.9.0./repository/conf/carbon.xml
```

will create new carbon.xml in proper directory and it will be used to configure ports.

Comment: U can check before and if offset variable isn't set then just copy carbon.original.org to carbon.xml

Answer (score 0):

Use -DportOffset= [offset value] when you start the server.

Ex:

```
./wso2server.sh -DportOffset=3
```